# iOS 12 Safari : XMLHttpRequest cannot load due to access control checks

Tags: javascript, cors, epson, ios12

I'm trying to use EPSON TM L-90 printer for printing labels from Javascript SDK 4.1.0. The XHR post call with following header works well in iOS 11 but fails in iOS 12.

The 'access control allow origin' is set as * from EPSON printer.

Both preflight and POST request fails with this error.

EPSON Javascript Library has following code.

```
xhr.open("POST", address, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", '""');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
// Check response
}
```

Any idea what could be the issue.?